# Converting prettified JSON back to normal

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, json

I got the below code from [JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unLSJ/) which helped me to beautify a json.

```
        if (!library)
           var library = {};

        library.json = {
           replacer: function(match, pIndent, pKey, pVal, pEnd) {
              var key = '<span class=json-key>';
              var val = '<span class=json-value>';
              var str = '<span class=json-string>';
              var r = pIndent || '';
              if (pKey)
                 r = r + key + pKey.replace(/[": ]/g, '') + '</span>: ';
              if (pVal)
                 r = r + (pVal[0] == '"' ? str : val) + pVal + '</span>';
              return r + (pEnd || '');
              },
           prettyPrint: function(obj) {
              var jsonLine = /^( *)("[\w]+": )?("[^"]*"|[\w.+-]*)?([,[{])?$/mg;
              return JSON.stringify(obj, null, 3)
                 .replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/\\"/g, '&quot;')
                 .replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
                 .replace(jsonLine, library.json.replacer);
              }
           };
```

But after making some minor edits in the beautified form, I want to get the json back into the normal form.

I tried it on a sample json

```
  { active: "<b>something</b>", codes: [48348, 28923, 39080], city: "London" }
```

What I did was given below.

```
var prettyJson = $("#prettyJsonContainer").text(); //this will strip all html tags
var pureJson = JSON.stringify(prettyJson);
```

But the result was

```
"{\n   active: \"<b>something</b>\",\n   codes: [\n      48348,\n      28923,\n      39080\n   ],\n   city: \"London\"\n}"
```

The expected Json was

```
     { active: "<b>something</b>", codes: [48348, 28923, 39080], city: "London" }
```

Please help.

Comment: As a side note: `{ active: "<b>something</b>", codes: [48348, 28923, 39080], city: "London" }` is not valid JSON, the keys (`active`, `codes`, `city`) must be wrapped in double quotes.

Comment: Why modify the data while in JSON format?  You should stick with modifying data an only output to JSON (whether prettfied or not) as needed.  JSON is a serialization format, not a mutable data structure.

Comment: @MikeBrant.. its all about how you make advantage of the strength of JSON. If you want to create a simple test interface for which the actual parameters can be very complex nested structures, it will be better to use JSON for setting the input parameters. And in such a scenario, I believe modification of JSON inputs are very much required.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding (and I probably am) but if it was still valid JSON after you made your changes couldn't you just re-parse and re-stringify?  `var newjson = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse( myjson ));`

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "{\n   active: \"<b>something</b>\",\n   codes: [\n      48348,\n      28923,\n      39080\n   ],\n   city: \"London\"\n}";
str = str.replace(/\\/g, "");
console.log(str);
```

This will remove \n and all the whitespace from the JSON and output will be like :

```
{
   active: "<b>something</b>",
   codes: [
      48348,
      28923,
      39080
   ],
   city: "London"
}
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rahulrulez/jq1ot5j5/

Comment: This is not the output the OP asked for.

Comment: He asked the same. I made whatever he needed as output. I know it is not a valid json

Comment: @RahulPatil Thanks for your valuable answer. But the problem is, i dont want this intended json output as you shown in the answer.